# Microservices application deployable in an old JavaEE application server

Tags: kubernetes, jakarta-ee, microservices, legacy, application-server

I've a big problem, and I hope that someone could help me!

I would like to refactor an old legacy JavaEE application.

The refactoring I've in my mind is very deep and I would like to redesign the application moving towards a microservices architecture using Java again.

Many frameworks exist for doing that, but I would like use one of the following: Quarkus (my favoutire), Microprofile and Vert.x.

The problem is that I got the indication that the new application must be deployable on old application servers, such as WebSpere 8.5.5, WebLogic 12c, and must be deployable in a Kubernetes environment without any application server.

Is there any way to meet this last requirement?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nope. Quarkus is stand-alone.  As is Vert.X. Microprofile is just a set of APIs - so that will happily run in a JavaEE context - although note that if the JavaEE server is _old_ it may well expose an older API than a modern framework would support. Modern frameworks that support JavaEE deployment include Spring Boot and Helidon (a Microprofile framework).

Comment: Hi Boris, thanks for your suggestions. I don't like Spring and regarding Helidon I didn't understand how to deploy a Helidon application in WebSphere or WebLogic. Do you have any suggestion about this last possibility, please?

Comment: I don't think you can simply take a microservice developed with quarkus/spring/... and deploy it on an applicaton server. however, you could make small JEE apps as either ejb modules or small war/ear archives. then you can deploy them on application server and you can create a container image from it and deploy it on kubernetes as well

Comment: @meaningqo, I know that there is this option, but I would like to use some modern framework. The problem is that only Spring Boot seems to be suitable for this purpose, but I consider it the worst framework among those available, because it is too heavy and slow. I tried to follow the suggestion by Boris about Helidon, but I think that it's not possible to deploy a Helidon application on a standard JavaEE application server.